# Replace Keywords

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my DB I have a longtext column that stores an email template.

I have a number of keywords in the template i.e `<<PersonName>>` or `<<ExpiryDate>>` that will be replaced with the individual details as provided in the current record.

Is there an easy way to cycle through a list of keywords and replace them dynamically. My initial approach was to have the KeyWord Name, placeholder text and corresponding query column name.

Then do a simple Replace loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Why not? I see no other method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could do it like this - a query with keyword, placeholder and value fields and then something like;

```
Dim strTempate as string
Dim rst as Recordset

strTemplate = <value of template field>

With rst
    Do Until .EOF
        strTemplate = Replace(strTemplate, Nz(!Placeholder,""), Nz(!Value,""))
        .Movenext
    Loop
End With
```

Which will loop through your keywords and make the replacements in your email template